# Is it advisable to use `const` for CommonJS requires?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, commonjs

In CommonJS (Node in particular), the `require()` variables are usually only assigned once and never changed. So is it a good practice to use the ES6 `const` for these? As in:

```js
const level = require('level');
```

instead of:

```js
var level = require('level');
```

What kind of good/bad effects will it have?

Comment: If you never modify it within the module, it won't have any good or bad effects.

Comment: If you're using ES6, I'd recommend to use ES6 module syntax as well :-)

Comment: @Bergi, of course, but in case of a transpiler like Traceur, you'd be [bound to use the old-fashioned `require`s](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Using-Traceur-with-Node.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, indeed, a good practice to use `const` for requires. Most current projects supporting Node 4+ do that, and there is virtually no scenario where you would want to modify a required module variable.

Answer (score 0):

Like Bergi said. You could/should use the ecmascript 6 module syntax.

```
import level from 'level';
```

I am **always** using the `const` keyword in es6 project (but not to require modules ;-) ). The IDE helps you to prevent simple errors. In my projects i never have to use `var` (or `let`).